Why does "COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" keep populating in Query Designer?
All of a sudden last week when I start to build my query in SSMS Query Designer, the columns are adding "COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and need an alias.  I don't think I changed any settings other then to add line numbers to my query, but I think that was several days before seeing this happen.  I set my settings back to default and it is still happening
Screenshot
I start with this, select all, right click and select Design Query in Editor.
NOTE: I can run this query without any errors
SELECT TOP (1000) [site_ref]
      ,[trans_num]
      ,[acct]
      ,[trans_date]
      ,[dom_amount]
      ,[ref]
      ,[vend_num]
      ,[voucher]
  FROM [dbo].[ledger_mst]

It then translate to this.
SELECT TOP (1000) site_ref COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS Expr1, trans_num, acct COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS Expr2, trans_date, dom_amount, ref COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS Expr3, 
                  vend_num COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS Expr4, voucher COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS Expr5
FROM     dbo.ledger_mst

I have been working on this project for almost two months and didn't have this issue until last week.
This happened to me five or more years ago.  It took me a week or two of googling to figure out the answer.  I can't remember how to fix it and I don't have two weeks to figure it out.  Please help!
I tried to reset my settings to default so "COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" was no longer being added to my view, but that didn't help.

You're better off notusing the query designer. It's outdated, feature lacking and often uses deprecated featurea. Learn the syntax to achieve your goals.

@ThomA I can and am doing it now, it just takes longer and time is of the essence.  Any other ideas?

Hire a consultant that knows what they are doing; that's probably the fastest (and most expensive) way.

From a user perspective, you can edit collation in options. If this doesn't fix it, it's happening at the database level, and would need to be altered by the database administrator.
Tools > Options >SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting


I checked this setting and it is already set to False.  Do you have any other ideas?
